# Jekyll website hosted on gh-pages via github. Need to use a custom URL

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, cname, base-url, custom-url

I am wanting to use a custom URL for this github website, but I ran into issues when I tried. The repo is below if you want to view my files. I had to do a 'git reset --hard "commit" ' to get it working again!

I dont know if I need to change my base URL too because none of the css worked, and no href links to other pages on the server worked either. Then I was getting build errors on github with no details as to why.

Steps I took:

1) I have a domain with godaddy

2) Then I went to github and changed the Custom url to the domain i have on github.

3) Then github created a cname file by its self with my url in it

4) I went to godaddy and pointed to the servers provided by github.

5) It display my html files, but no href links work, and CSS is not working. I think it has something to do with the base url or something...

https://github.com/jose-reyes-9/school-amp-1

Comment: Could you please proved a link for the domain you have this site hosted on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In _config.yml change :

```
baseurl: ""
url: "http://yourcustome-domain-url.com"
```

And add a CNAME because github doesn't create it for you.

Comment: Thanks, I will try then wait for DNS to update. See you back in 24hrs - 48hrs.

Comment: Sorry, i didnt come back here. I just checked. https://wshsamplified.com